# How to import Firebase Firestore into a create-react-app project using ES6 syntax

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ecmascript-6, create-react-app, es6-modules

I'm having trouble getting Firebase Firestore to work with the basic create-react-app boilerplate. Does anyone have a working sample?

The [Get Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) doc only explains how to set it up with `require` statements, whereas I'd like to use ES6 imports.

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/firestore");
```

What is the ES6 equivalent of `require('firebase/firestore')`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/datastore';
```

From https://github.com/firebase/reactfire#using-the-firebase-js-sdk-in-react

Comment: Works for me too.

Answer (score 3):

My trouble was that I was trying to use ES6 syntax. The Firebase docs say to access it via something like:

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
require('firebase/firestore');
```

Whereas I wanted to do something like this:

```
import * as Firebase from 'firebase';
import Firestore from 'firebase/firestore';
```

That didn't seem to work, but this does:

```
import * as Firebase from 'firebase';
require('firebase/firestore');
```

I don't like mixing `import` and `require`, but good enough for now.

Answer (score 3):

Two months later, this is working for me:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import '@firebase/firestore';
```

(It also works without the '@'.)

Here's the dependencies section from my package.json:

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "@firebase/app": "^0.2.0",
        "@firebase/firestore": "^0.4.1",
        "firebase": "^4.13.1",
        "react": "^16.3.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
        "react-router": "^4.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
        "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
    },
    ...
}
```

I started out following the [instructions on npmjs.com for the firebase package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase).  In its dependencies, I found [@firebase/firestore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/firestore), and tried to follow those instructions, which say to import like this:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/firestore'
```

However, this method of importing firebase didn't work for me -- I was able to initialize my app, but trying to execute `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)` caused an error:

> TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__firebase_app**.default.auth is
>   not a function

Answer (score 1):

I created a config file for firebase:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const config = { /* COPY THE ACTUAL CONFIG FROM FIREBASE CONSOLE */
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "domen.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://domen.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "lavs-mercury",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "id"
};

export default firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Then I just import this module to file where I want to use. For example:

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';
import firebase from "../../firebase-module";

export const logout = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
    return {
        type: actionTypes.LOGOUT
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm looking for help with getting the new [Firebase Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) (currently in beta) set up. Your config doesn't appear to reference Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Make sure you have installed npm install --save firebase

import  'firebase/firestore';

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by downgrading the firebase version to 7.

`"firebase": "^7.7.0"`