# How to use the firebase.auth without initializing firebase again in my Account file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-redux

I'm getting this error because firebase is being initialized again inside my account.js file. I want to use firebase.auth so my account.js file will show the login form when signed out and display a sign out button when signed in. Is there a correct way to do this? [image]

**Account.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Card, Button, Spinner, CardSection } from '../common';
import LoginForm from '../LoginForm';
import router from '../../config/router';

class Account extends React.Component {
  state = { loggedIn: false };

  componentWillMount() {
    firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'sksssk',
    authDomain: 'ssjkjskjs',
    databaseURL: 'skhskjhsk',
    projectId: 'sijisj',
    messagingSenderId: 'jwuduwid'
  });
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    //event handler that handles either signing in or signing out
    if (user) {
      this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
    }
  });
    }
    renderContent() {
      if (this.state.loggedIn) {
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Tabs />
            <Button>
              Log Out
            </Button>
          </Provider>
        );
      }
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { loggedIn: false };

  //lifecyle method for firebase initialization
  componentWillMount() {
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: 'sksssk',
        authDomain: 'ssjkjskjs',
        databaseURL: 'skhskjhsk',
        projectId: 'sijisj',
        messagingSenderId: 'jwuduwid'
  });
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  //event handler that handles either signing in or signing out
  if (user) {
    this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
  } else {
    this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
  }
});
  }
  renderContent() {
    if (this.state.loggedIn) {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Tabs />
        </Provider>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Tabs />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Initialize firebase with your settings in a separate file. Export the instance of firebase as a default export. Import that instance wherever you need it.

Comment: can you be more specific or provide some code on how to do that?

Comment: ...Any reason you can't use plain JavaScript? ...React appears highly complicated to me.

Comment: It is but I like the React Native framework responisveness

Comment: It’s really just creating an instance once and exporting it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48978285/5059657

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to ensure the initialization is in a place that only executes once, as Alexander commented.

Alternatively, I sometimes just detect if Firebase was already initialized:

```
if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  var config = {
    ...
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
```

Note that the above snippet won't work if you use multiple `FirebaseApp` instances in your app.