# Using ES6 "import default,export default" syntax in firebase project

Tags: firebase

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH892.png)I succesfully initialized my project into my folder using `firebase init` command and now I have all necessary dependencies and files.My question is how can I use ES6 syntax in firebase project.I looked through a few videos on youtube and they all were using `const .... = require('...')` syntax.Thank you a lot.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978232/how-to-import-firebase-firestore-into-a-create-react-app-project-using-es6-synta). Might help.

Answer (score 0):

To use ES6 features like import and const, and even ES7 features like await and async, use [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) by renaming index.js to index.ts.

Example index.ts:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, resp) => {
 resp.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Comment: thanks but I used to use this syntax inside js files,why ts now?I mean I always use this syntax inside React project(I've added a screenshot)